# Are the groups $(\Bbb Q^+,*)$ where $\Bbb Q^+$ isomorphic to $(A,*)$ where $A=\{\frac{p}{q}\in \Bbb Q^+:p,q\text{are odd}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Are the groups $(\Bbb Q^+,*)$ where $\Bbb Q^+$ denotes set of positive rationals isomorphic to $(A,*)$  where $A=\{\frac{p}{q}\in \Bbb Q^+:p,q\text{are odd}\}$ ?

I tried $f:(\Bbb Q^+,*)\to (A,*) $ by $f(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{2a+1}{2b+1}$ but alas it's not even a homomorphism.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Map $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{m_k}\mapsto \prod_{k=1}^\infty p_{k+1}^{m_k}$$
where the $p_k$ are the primes (and $p_1=2$).

Comment: I am not getting this at all.If $\frac{a}{b}$ is any element of $\Bbb Q^+$ how are you mapping this to $A$

Comment: Are you taking $a=p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\dots p_k^{m_k}$

Comment: Why is the product in your answer infinite then?

Comment: @Mathematics : Note. $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots$ are the enumeration of the prime numbers. Any homomorphism on $\mathbb{Q}$ is determined by the value it takes at prime numbers since $f$ is multiplicative. So assume $p_{1}=2,p_{2}=3,p_{3}=5$ and so on. Take a say $16 \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$. So $2^{4} \mapsto 3^{4}$ under the above map which Hagen has mentioned. Once you know the value of homomorphism at integers you can easily figure out what value it will take at rationals.